# Validate xml element's value using Xml validator dtd

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a Xml message with DTD defined in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE note [
  <!ELEMENT note (to)>
  <!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST to Value CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<note>
<to></to> 
</note>
```

I want my validator to check that

```
<to>Hello</to> is correct and 
<to></to> or <to/> is incorrect.
```

How can I achieve that using DTD ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done with DTDs; DTDs have no facility for requiring a minimum number of characters in a #PCDATA element.  That was one of the motivating use cases for the development of XSD.